# How to set separator for Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox id attribute?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have created a multicheckbox element using this way:

```php
$furniture = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('furnishing');
$furniture->setLabel('furniture')
    ->setMultiOptions(array(
     'computer_table' => 'Table for computer',
     'coffee_table' => 'Cofee table',
    ))
    ->setDecorators($formMultipleDecorators)
    ->setOptions(array('class' => 'form-checkbox'))
    ->setSeparator('');
```

This code add to form next html code:

```html
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="furnishing[]" id="furnishing-computer_table" value="computer-table" class="form-checkbox">Table for computer
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="furnishing[]" id="furnishing-coffee_table" value="coffee-table" class="form-checkbox">Cofee table
</label>
```

Is it possible to set input id to "furnishing_computer_table" instead of "furnishing-computer_table"?

Comment: I believe this is Zend Framework internas, which are hard to change in version 1.

Comment: I thought so too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 ->setOptions(array('class' => 'form-checkbox'))
```

To:

```
 ->setOptions(array('class' => 'form-checkbox','id'=>'furnishing_computer_table'))
```